# FoxPro 2.6 EXE - Open with cmd.exe

Tags: command-prompt, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a legacy application which was created using FoxPro 2.6

I had to make some changed to this program. I made the changed and then re-built the EXE however now when I launch the application it opens in Microsoft FoxPro. It use to open in Command Prompt which was slightly more user-friendly.

Any ideas of how I can get this to run with command prompt?

Thanks,

Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was using FoxPro for DOS, I was originally trying to use FoxPro for Windows.

Jack.